# Copy across data in new spreadsheet if it matches criteria from original spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010

2 different spreadsheets

```
If Column B (Name) is = to "ABC Co" 'from Sheet2
```

and

```
If Column C (Category) is = to "A" 'from Sheet2

Copy "Part#" from Column A (Sheet2) into Sheet1
```

Note: Duplicate values can be found in column B (Name) and Column C (Category) as per the example on Sheet2, no duplicate in Column A (Part#)

```
**Sheet2**  

            Column A    Column B     Column C
    Row 1   Part#       Name:        Category: 
    Row 2   12340000    ABC Co          A
    Row 3   12340001    DDD Inc         A
    Row 4   12340002    Alpha Co        A
    Row 5   12340003    ABC Co          A
    Row 6   12340004    Alpha Co        B
    Row 7   12340005    DDD Inc         B
    Row 8   12340006    ABC Co          B
```

Output Required:

```
 *Sheet1*   

                 Column A
         Row 1   12340000
         Row 2   12340003
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance, just an FYI, I have spent a fair bit of time searching for an answer however haven't had any luck, not too familiar with the terminology required to assist with my search and also tweaking to suit my individual case is not my best strength.... hope there are no rules I have overlooked however if so, if you could please let me know I would be happy to correct.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just filter for your results?  Must they be on a separate sheet?

Comment: @Alicia Do you know how to use VBA?

Comment: Hi Chrismas007 - No experience with VBA :(

Comment: Hi Marc - Filtering is not feasible as there are approx. 20 spreadsheets to be updated regularly pulling data from 1 main source, also I will need to modify the formula slightly as I have more than 1 type of condition to search on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

I hope i am clear in my comments otherwise just ask me.

Option Explicit

```
Sub MATCH()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of the sheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change the name of the sheet
Dim ws2Lastrow As Long, i As Long

ws2Lastrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the lastrow in the Sheet(2)

With ws2 ' Work within the sheet(2)

For i = 2 To ws2Lastrow 'Start the Loop from row2 until the last row

'Put your two condition in order to copy the value in column Part#
' If the value in column B = "ABC Co" and column C = "A"
        If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "ABC Co" And .Cells(i, "C").Value = "A" Then

        'Past the value in Sheet(1) column A in the first empty cell
            ws1.Cells(ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A") = .Cells(i, "A").Value

        End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Manu - Thank you very much, I will try shortly and come back with my results and or questions!

Comment: Actually just taking a further look... is this a VBA script?

Comment: Hi again Manu... Just checked my tags and realized there was an excel-vba in there, I am very sorry, I don't know how I added that one in as I am not familiar with VBA..... I have now removed... wondering if you would know of a formula instead to use? Or for VBA is there any easy way to explain how to input this code?